# Write a Box and push in array but dont show

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i want to push a box in ArrayBox but i dont want to ahow the box on chart, if i change color to color.new(x , 100) its show the box with no color.

or if i remove the box with boz.delete(x) the calculate will fail..

please help me to push the box and no draw it

```
//@version=5
//This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
indicator('Super OrderBlock / FVG / BoS Tools by makuchaku & eFe', overlay=true, max_boxes_count=500, max_lines_count=500 , max_labels_count=500)

plotOB = input.bool(defval=true, title='Plot OB', group='Order Blocks')
obBullColor = input.color(defval=color.new(color.green, 90), title='Bullish OB Color', inline='Set Custom Color', group='Order Blocks')
obBearColor = input.color(defval=color.new(color.red, 90), title='Bearish OB Color', inline='Set Custom Color', group='Order Blocks')
obBoxBorder = input.string(defval=line.style_solid, title='OB Box Border Style', options=[line.style_dashed, line.style_dotted, line.style_solid], group='Order Blocks', tooltip='To disable border, set Border Width below to 0')
obBorderTransparency = input.int(defval=80, title='OB Border Box Transparency', minval=0, maxval=100, group='Order Blocks')
obMaxBoxSet = input.int(defval=10, title='Maximum OB Box Displayed', minval=1, maxval=100, group='Order Blocks', tooltip='Minimum = 1, Maximum = 100')
filterMitOB = input.bool(defval=true, title='Custom Color Mitigated OB', group='Order Blocks')
mitOBColor = input.color(defval=color.new(color.yellow, 20), title='Mitigated OB Color', group='Order Blocks', inline='Set Custom Color Mit OB', tooltip='Set Transparency to 0 to make mitigated OB disappear')

plotLabelOB = input.bool(defval=true, title='Plot OB Label', inline='OB label', group='Label Options')
obLabelColor = input.color(defval=color.gray, title='Color', inline='OB label', group='Label Options')
obLabelSize = input.string(defval=size.tiny, title="Size", options=[size.huge, size.large, size.small, size.tiny, size.auto, size.normal], inline='OB label', group='Label Options')

//Box Types
var int _ob  = 1
var int _fvg = 2
var int _rjb = 3
var int _bos = 4

//Box Labels
var string _obLabel  = "OB"
var string _fvgLabel = "FVG"
var string _rjbLabel = "RJB"
var string _bosLabel = "BoS"
var string _plus     = "+"
var string _minus    = "-"
var string _empty    = ""

//Box Arrays
var box[] _bearBoxesOB  = array.new_box()
var box[] _bullBoxesOB  = array.new_box()

//Functions
isUp(index) =>
    close[index] > open[index]

isDown(index) =>
    close[index] < open[index]

isObUp(index) =>
    isDown(index + 1) and isUp(index) and close[index] > high[index + 1]

isObDown(index) =>
    isUp(index + 1) and isDown(index) and close[index] < low[index + 1]

isFvgUp(index) =>
    (low[index] > high[index + 2])

isFvgDown(index) =>
    (high[index] < low[index + 2])


//Function to Calculte Box Length
_controlBox(_boxes, _high, _low, _type) =>
    var box_right1 = 0
    var box_right2 = 0
    var box_right3 = 0
    if array.size(_boxes) > 0
        for i = array.size(_boxes) - 1 to 0 by 1
            _box = array.get(_boxes, i)
            _boxLow = box.get_bottom(_box)
            _boxHigh = box.get_top(_box)
            _boxRight = box.get_right(_box)
        
            if (_type == _ob) 
                if na or (bar_index == _boxRight and not((_high > _boxLow and _low < _boxLow) or (_high > _boxHigh and _low < _boxHigh)))
                    box.set_right(_box, bar_index + 1)
                else
                    if _type == _ob
                        box.set_bgcolor(_box, mitOBColor)
                        box.set_border_color(_box, mitOBColor)
////////////////// Pivots //////////////////// 

if isObUp(1) and plotOB
    _bullboxOB = box.new(left=bar_index - 2, top=high[2], right=bar_index, bottom=math.min(low[2], low[1]), border_color=color.new(obBullColor, obBorderTransparency), border_style=obBoxBorder, border_width=1, bgcolor=obBullColor, 
     text=plotLabelOB ? _obLabel  + _plus : _empty, text_halign=text.align_right, text_valign=text.align_bottom, text_size=obLabelSize, text_color=obLabelColor)
    if array.size(_bullBoxesOB) > obMaxBoxSet
        box.delete(array.shift(_bullBoxesOB))
    array.push(_bullBoxesOB, _bullboxOB)

//Bearish OB Box Plotting
if isObDown(1) and plotOB
    _bearboxOB = box.new(left=bar_index - 2, top=math.max(high[2], high[1]), right=bar_index, bottom=low[2], border_color=color.new(obBearColor, obBorderTransparency), border_style=obBoxBorder, border_width=1, bgcolor=obBearColor, 
     text=plotLabelOB ? _obLabel  + _minus : _empty, text_halign=text.align_right, text_valign=text.align_bottom, text_size=obLabelSize, text_color=obLabelColor)
    if array.size(_bearBoxesOB) > obMaxBoxSet
        box.delete(array.shift(_bearBoxesOB))
    array.push(_bearBoxesOB, _bearboxOB)

if plotOB
    _controlBox(_bearBoxesOB, high, low, _ob)
    _controlBox(_bullBoxesOB, high, low, _ob)
```

plese help me , i cant push a box and dont show it

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Changing the "`Mitigated OB Color`" input such that the transparency is 100 will make the boxes disappear. You can just not show that as an input if you do not want to see the boxes at all.

Comment: i use this code in screener that have 0 to 10 number , if i use transparency its goint to high number and if i use in btcusdt , its show the 50,000 number but my screener just have 0 to 10 number . please help me

Comment: `Mitigated OB Color` is a *color* input. The transparency values will only vary from 0 to 100, no matter what.